# preg_match for phone number and email

Tags: php, validation, preg-match, contact-form

Is there a preg_match to check if an input field contains either a phone number or email address?

I'm working on a contact form and want to simplify the process of user contact.

many thanks

Comment: Have you search anything or read the [php docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.examples.validation.php) ?

Comment: Phone number is almost impossible (without restrictions) email... sure: http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

Comment: copy and paste the question title in google and you will get dozens of results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a simple function which checks for both email and phone number.
For email you can use `filter_var(email_value, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)` and for phone number you can find tons of regex.

Comment: so an if statement to detect whether the first character is a number or letter?